# unable to sepcify backup in terraform cosmodb

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cosmosdb

I am using terraform to create CosmoDB , my build uses azurerm 2.56.0

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "testaccount" {
    name = "testaccount"
    location = var.location
    resource_group_name = var.rgname
    offer_type = "Standard"
    Kind = "GlobalDocumentDB"
    enable_automatic_failover = false
  
  consistent_policy {
         consistency_level = "Session"
    }
    
    backup {
         type = "Periodic"
         interval_in_minutes = "120"
         retention_in_hours = "14"
    }
}
```

I am getting following error
Error: Unsupported block type

When I comment out the backup section, it works fine.
I checked cosmosdb account https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account#backup

it does seem like I have declared it correctly. I have also checked that this version of azurerm supports backups

I am probably missing something obvious, does anyone see what the problem is?
Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`backup` is **not supported** in `2.56.0`. You are looking at newer docs. For your version, the docs are [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/2.56.0/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account).

If you want to use `backup`, you have to **upgrade your provider**.